# Embed Interop Types in F#

Tags: com, f#, com-interop

Can we embed interop type in F# ?

First I dont see the option to do so in the references.

Second, if I embed the type in C#, it tells me to reference the interface and not the concrete class:

```
//DBEngine is the interface DBEngineClass is the concrete class

//if I dont embed the interop

//Valid
var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngineClass();
//Valid
var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine();


//if I do embed the interop
//Invalid
var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngineClass();
//Valid
var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine();
```

However, F# always wants to have a reference to the concrete class.
Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 2):

Tao Liu talks about some additional work you have to do from F# to discover the correct class to instanciate [here](http://apollo13cn.blogspot.se/2012/04/trick-in-f-interop.html). To my knowledge, there is no way to embed the interop types. I would be happy to be proven wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but this works fine, referencing v14.0:

```
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao
let dbe = DBEngineClass() :> DBEngine
```

Comment: It does indeed, but you still instruct the binary to actually bind to the version v14.0 specific class. COM has this notion of interface, which is surfaced at langage level in C# apparently now. which is why you can new-up... an interface !

Comment: The idea being that I dont care which client library will implement the interface. I push this genericity down to the runtime, who is in charge of complying to it.